# Distance between ions

Tags: ions

I am doing a homework where I am supposed to calculate estimate od distance between two ions in cytoplasm. I have only been given the concentration of an ion. Any help how I should start looking this problem?

Only solution I have been able to create is the one where you force some number out from consentration by using ion radius and assume them all to have same distance. However, this feels too, I dunno, mechanical way to solve this problem.

Comment: If that's all the information you've been given then I'd probably personally go with something like your solution. Work out the available volume to each ion $V$, work out the corresponding radius $V = 4\pi r^3/3$, then the distance between each ion is $2r$. But I don't know, maybe there's something better.